# Android RecyclerView content description

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, talkback, accessibility

Is it possible to set `contentDescription` or some similar attribute for the whole `RecyclerView` so that a screen reader app like TalkBack would read this `contentDescription` when the list is first reached and only then proceed to list items?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the content description for RecyclerView, it will be announced by Talkback. Instead of a generic "In list" announcement, the user will hear "In list ". This can be used as a short description to better explain the purpose of the list, like a name for the list. It will also be used to announce when the user navigates away from the list.

This is not the expected place to put in a longer explanation, as it is used both to enter and leave the list. If you need to add additional information, a better approach would be to have some sort of label before the RecyclerView, so it's available for all users, not just via Talkback.